# Difference between copy and assign slice golang

Tags: go

Hi everyone I hope you guys doing well, I was reading [the copy build-in function](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#copy), and I was wondering what was the difference between straight assign value from `arr` to `tmp` and copy the value from `arr` to `tmp`? since both will have the same result both value and cap and length of `arr` slice. [here's the golang playground](https://play.golang.org/p/CYBXZcuAVtY).

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    arr := []int{1, 2, 3}
    tmp := make([]int, len(arr))
    copy(tmp, arr)
    fmt.Println(tmp)
    fmt.Println(arr)
    fmt.Println(cap(tmp))
    fmt.Println(len(tmp))

    tmp2 := arr
    fmt.Println(tmp2) 
    fmt.Println(cap(tmp2))
    fmt.Println(len(tmp2))
}
```

the result is,

```
[1 2 3]
[1 2 3]
3
3
[1 2 3]
3
3
```

if they had a difference what will it be and can you explain it with an example, please and thank you for your time and consideration :)

Comment: See https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro and https://blog.golang.org/slices (and of course the Tour of Go).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The backing array of `tmp` is a copy of the the backing array from `arr`.

The slices `tmp2` and `arr` share the same backing array.

See this code:

```
arr := []int{1, 2, 3}
tmp := make([]int, len(arr))
copy(tmp, arr)

tmp2 := arr

arr[0] = 22
fmt.Println(arr)  // prints [22 2 3]
fmt.Println(tmp)  // prints [1 2 3]
fmt.Println(tmp2) // prints [22 2 3]
```

Notice how changing an element in `arr` also changed in element in `tmp2`, but not `tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

As Muffin already answered, slice data structure is a pointer to an array. So if you assign to a new variable, it is still a pointer to the same array. That's why, any changes you make to the slice is reflected back to the array it represents.

Also, a new slice is initialised with a small capacity (array length). Once it is fully occupied, it has to create a new array and copy all its content from the old to new array.